# How to validate a date in textbox, on which calendar is implemented?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, calendar

I have implemented a `jquery calender` on asp.net `textbox` control. When I click on `textbox` it shows popup calendar, from which a `date` can be selected.

Now,the issue is I have to **validate that the date selected cannot be a past date**.
Today's date and date greater than today** are valid.

I have used `javascript` to call the calendar on the `textbox`.

**I used the code below:**

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEventDate").datepicker();
```

I searched a lot on various websites but not getting any idea.

**Note:** I have declared script in master page's head and the calendar control is on content page and I do not want page reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `minDate` option in jquery

```
<input type="text" id="datep" name="datpicker"/>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datep").datepicker({
        minDate: 0
    });
});
</script>
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tDb4/)

Comment: @Karthik-- i appreciate your effort but my problem is how can i compare that the date selected is a past date??? can u give snippet of  javacript??

Comment: @kartik i am using To asp.net text boxes for date from_date and to_date . and want to validate both